# Show all rows with some special condition rows

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables:

#### Items

```
item_id      is_private    created_by    stock_id
   1              0            1             4
   2              1            2             5
   3              0            3             8
```

#### Stocks

```
stock_id      created_by
    4              1
    5              2
    6              3
```

Where `created_by` column in both tables refer to `users` table's `ID`.

I am trying to get the item rows fetching by a user. If the user has created an `is_private` row, then that row should add to the result.

I want the result to be flexible based on the user accessing the information.

### For Example:

***if `user_id: 3` is accessing the above information***:

```
item_id       created_by    stock_id
   1             1             4
   3             3             8
```

***if `user_id: 2` is accessing the above information***:

```
item_id       created_by    stock_id
   1             1             4
   2             2             5
   3             3             8
```

In the above, I got three rows because the `user_id: 2` has created a `is_private: 1` (*if you check the `items` table*)

I tried the following:

```
SELECT 
   item_id, created_by, stock_id
FROM items
```

^ Clearly, in the above tried query I don't know how to do this.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding the logic which determines your expected output.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So far what I've understood : records having `is_private=0` are public to anybody. So a particular user can access only those public records + the records created by him.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The resultant rows based on the query should depend upon the user accessing the information. If a row has `is_private: 1` and that row was created by the user accessing the information, then that row should also be visible in the resultant rows otherwise it should not.

Comment: @1000111 Your query looks right under this assumption, but then the question seems too simple for the asker's rep level.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, perhaps Mr_Green got his rep from questions in non-SQL topics.

Comment: @BillKarwin An excellent explanation.

Comment: Second that.... I was strange at first sight with @Mr_Green repo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT item_id,
       created_by,
       stock_id
FROM items 
WHERE is_private = 0 OR
      created_by = :user_id
```

Comment: `SELECT 
   item_id, created_by, stock_id
` is looking better than `SELECT *`.

Comment: It always @RohanKumar :). Btw, Tim is acting as an event listener to this answer :p .Thanks Tim!

Comment: Just realized it is way more complicated than what I presented here. Anyway, thanks :)